# Julia: How to insert a specific row of matrix inside a specific row of another one

Tags: matrix, julia

I have the following matrix:

```
L = [3 6  18 92 2
     2 24 39 59 3];
```

I intend to enter the first row of matrix `L` into the 2nd row of the following matrix:

```
X = [2 7  43 52 1
     4 21 14 97 4
     3 17 27 85 5];
```

And the result should be:

```
Xnew = [2 7  43 52 1
        3 6  18 92 2
        4 21 14 97 4
        3 17 27 85 5];
```

How can I do that in Julia?

Answer (score 4):

This is a way to do it:

```
julia> @views [X[1:1, :]; L[1:1, :]; X[2:end, :]]
4×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 2   7  43  52  1
 3   6  18  92  2
 4  21  14  97  4
 3  17  27  85  5
```

You could get the same without `@views` but it would be less efficient as it would create intermediate copies of data.